# When is the Builder pattern preferable to inheritance and multiple implementations?

Tags: java, design-patterns, builder

When does it make sense to use a builder pattern like:

```
private static final Foo FOO1 = Foo.Builder().setX(...).setY(...).setZ(...).build();
private static final Foo FOO2 = Foo.Builder().setX(...).setY(...).setZ(...).build();
private static final Foo FOO3 = Foo.Builder().setX(...).setY(...).setZ(...).build();
... x100 ...
```

VS something like

```
public class MyFoos {
  public static class Foo1 implements Foo {
    public String getX() {...}
    public String getY() {...}
    public String getZ() {...}
  }

  public static class Foo2 implements Foo {
    public String getX() {...}
    public String getY() {...}
    public String getZ() {...}
  }

  public static class Foo3 implements Foo {
    public String getX() {...}
    public String getY() {...}
    public String getZ() {...}
  }
  ... x100...
}
```

Does it matter how complex Foo is?  For example, let's say if we used a Foo.Builder(), we might need to call something like:

Foo.Builder().setSpecialFunction(new Function() {...})

where Function is something like http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html

does that suggest that the Builder pattern is not appropriate in this situation?  If not, what would be preferable?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The second design choise is terrible - do not abuse inheritance. Builder pattern (according to  Bloch's "Effective Java") is appropriate to use when number of parameters in constructors is more than some constant (say 4, according to Bloch).